# keyboard hide behind the textfield

Tags: flutter, dart

hii i'm creating a 8 or more textfield in column but when i click on textfield keyboard appear but last textfield makes hide please guys help me :
i tried several things like `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,` , `final bottom = MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom;`
this is my code :-

```
 final bottom = MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom;
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        reverse: true,
        // padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: bottom),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            _viewOnlyItemCell('ID', _accountInfoData!.iD.toString() ?? ''),
            _viewOnlyItemCell('Account Name', _accountInfoData!.accountName ?? ''),
            _viewOnlyItemCell('Account ID', _accountInfoData!.accountID ?? ''),
            _accountType(),
            _editableItemCell('Phone', 'Enter Phone Number', _phone, _onChangePhoneNo),
            _editableItemCell('Fax', 'Enter Fax Number', _fax, _onChangeFax),
            _editableItemCell('Email', 'Enter Email ID', _email, _onChangeEmail),
            _editableItemCell('Website', 'Enter Website', _website, _onChangeWebsite),
            _editableItemCell('Mailing Address 1', 'Enter Mailing Address 1', _mailingAddress1, _onChangeMailingAddressOne),
            _editableItemCell('Mailing Address 2', 'Enter Mailing Address 2', _mailingAddress2, _onChangeMailingAddressTwo),
            _editableItemCell('Mailing City', 'Enter Mailing City', _mailingCity, _onChangeMailingCity),
            _editableItemCell('Mailing State', 'Enter Mailing State', _mailingState, _onChangeMailingState),
            _editableItemCell('Mailing Zip', 'Enter Mailing Zip', 
// error here :-  _mailingZip, _onChangeMailingZip),
            _groupName(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

i'm expecting when keyboard appear on last textfield , textfield scroll along with keyboard

Answer (score 0):

try to wrap the SingleChildScrollview with a SizedBox and give the Sizedbox  full Height

like :
`SizedBox(height:MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,child:SingleChildScrollView())`

set the   resizeToAvoidBottomInset to false:

```
resizeToAvoidBottomInset :false
```

the textfield will appear if you scroll the page.

Comment: i tried but not working

Comment: when you try to scroll manualy,the texfields appears?